# Passport JS authentication issue - Running on NodeJS - Getting error 503 - H13 on Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, heroku, passport.js

I've searched all over and read many similar situations, but none of them quite similar to mine. I've created an API running on NodeJS with PostgreSQL database. I've used passport for authentication with passport-local.

This is where I declared the config for Passport:

```
const express = require("express");

const auth = express.Router();

const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const pool = require("../../config/dbConfig");
require("dotenv").config();
const session = require("express-session");
const flash = require("express-flash");
const passport = require("passport");

const initializePassport = require("../../config/passportConfig");

initializePassport(passport);

auth.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
auth.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
  })
);

auth.use(passport.initialize());
auth.use(passport.session());
auth.use(flash());

const checkAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return res.redirect("/api/auth/dashboard");
  }
  next();
};

const checkNotAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    next();
  }
  res.redirect("/api/auth/login");
};

auth.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.redirect("/api/auth/login");
});
auth.get("/login", checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.render("login");
});
auth.get("/signup", checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.render("signup");
});
auth.get("/dashboard", checkNotAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.render("dashboard", { user: req.user.first_name });
});

auth.post("/signup", async (req, res) => {
  const { email, first_name, last_name, username, password, password2 } =
    req.body;

  let errors = [];

  if (
    !email ||
    !first_name ||
    !last_name ||
    !username ||
    !password ||
    !password2
  ) {
    errors.push({ message: "All fields need to be filled." });
  }

  if (password.length < 6) {
    errors.push({ message: "Password needs to be 6 characters or more." });
  }

  if (password !== password2) {
    errors.push({
      message: "The two passwords do not match. Please try again.",
    });
  }

  if (errors.length > 0) {
    res.render("signup", { errors });
  } else {
    //Form validation passed

    let hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

    pool.query(
      "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $1",
      [email],
      (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        }
        if (results.rows.length > 0) {
          errors.push({
            message:
              "The email has already been used. Please login or use a different email.",
          });
          res.render("signup", { errors });
        } else {
          pool.query(
            "INSERT INTO users (email, password, first_name, last_name, username) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5);",
            [email, hashedPassword, first_name, last_name, username],
            (err, results) => {
              if (err) {
                throw err;
              }
              req.flash(
                "success_msg",
                "You are now registered. Please login to continue."
              );
              res.redirect("/api/auth/login");
            }
          );
        }
      }
    );
  }
});

auth.post(
  "/login",
  passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/api/auth/dashboard",
    failureRedirect: "/api/auth/login",
    failureFlash: true,
  })
);

auth.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
  req.logOut();
  req.flash("success_msg", "You have been succesfuly logged out.");
  res.redirect("/api/auth/login");
});

module.exports = auth;
```

Everything ran smoothly on local, but once I've deployed on Heroku, I get an error 503/H13:

```
heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/api/auth/dashboard" host=salty-ridge-11669.herokuapp.com request_id=5344a940-61ab-4f35-bb49-68a05b76ea12 fwd="94.4.235.211" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

I've tried to use a custom function and pass req.redirect to the passport.authenticate (instead of successRedirect). From what I could gather online is some sort of issue with the https ? But the request is just to redirect so I really can't understand.

Answer (score 0):

ok, mystery solved.
It was simply a missing else statement in the middleware I created:

```
  const checkAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return res.redirect("/api/auth/dashboard");
  } else { //HERE
  next();
 }
};

const checkNotAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    next();
  }else{ //AND HERE
}
  res.redirect("/api/auth/login");
};
```

For some reason, the fact that I was calling next() was enough in my brain.

Now both the local and Heroku deployed versions are working :)